# how can I make this data in separated columns

Tags: bash, text-processing

```
Frequencies -- 1403.6738 1403.6738 1403.6738
IR Inten -- 25.0809 25.0809 25.0809
```

I want to get two columns

```
Frequencies     IR Inten
1403.6738       25.0809
```

and so on

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you tell us how large these files are approximately (i.e. how many entries)

Comment: What should "and so on" look like? Should there be a new header for the next pair of values? The example data is not to large, so maybe you could give a more complete expected output.

Comment: No, I want to complete the number of frequencies under it and the number of IR become under the IR
like two column
Frequencies    IR Inten
1403.6738        25.0809
 1403.6738       25.0809

Comment: If you need, I can explain more

Comment: Ok, just to be sure--each "Frequency" value pairs up with an "IR Inten" value? There are no blanks, extra-spaces, NAs, etc.? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (the programming language formerly known as Perl6)**

Raku has a nifty `Z` operator for problems like this, to 'zip up' items, one from each list:

```
~$ raku -e 'my @array1 = lines(); put ( [Z] @array1[0].words, @array1[1].words).join("\n");'  Freq_IR.txt
Frequencies IR_Inten
-- --
1403.6738 25.0809
1403.6738 25.0809
1403.6738 25.0809
```

Note: I had to correct the header line above so that the second column is titled  "`IR_Inten`". You can edit by hand or run the code below, prior to rearranging the data with the code above:

```
~$ raku -pe 's/IR \s Inten/IR_Inten/;'  Freq_IR.txt > Freq_IR2.txt
```

HTH.

https://raku.org
https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#Zip_metaoperator
[https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-[+]_(reduction_metaoperators)](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-%5B+%5D_(reduction_metaoperators))

Comment: If you used `.comb` with a regex instead of `.words` you don't need the preprocess step. `~$ raku -e '.put for [Z] lines>>.comb: /[<:L>+]+ % \s+ || \S+/'` (runs of `<:L>etters` separated by `[\s]paces` or a run of `non-[\S]paces`.) Other options for the regex `/^ .* <before " -"> | \S+/` or `/ "IR Inten" | \S+ /` I also simplified it by removing the needless array. Note that you can write `( [Z] … )` as `[Z]‍( … )`

Comment: @BradGilbert Please feel free to post a solution (Answer). Writing  `( [Z] … )` as `[Z]‍( … )` returns the data in "wide" format which is identical to the OP's input, i.e. \n `Frequencies -- 1403.6738 1403.6738 1403.6738`\n
`IR_Inten -- 25.0809 25.0809 25.0809`

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk -F' -- ' -v OFS='\t' '
    { hdr[NR]=$1; n=split($2,v," "); for (i in v) vals[NR,i]=v[i] }
    END { print hdr[1], hdr[2]; for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print vals[1,i], vals[2,i] }
' file
Frequencies     IR Inten
1403.6738       25.0809
1403.6738       25.0809
1403.6738       25.0809
```

and to work for any number of output rows and columns:

```
awk -F' -- ' -v OFS='\t' '
    { hdr[NR]=$1; n=split($2,v," "); for (i in v) vals[NR,i]=v[i] }
    END {
        for (c=1; c<=NR; c++) {
            printf "%s%s", hdr[c], (c<NR ? OFS : ORS)
        }
        for (r=1; r<=n; r++) {
            for (c=1; c<=NR; c++) {
                printf "%s%s", vals[c,r], (c<NR ? OFS : ORS)
            }
        }
    }
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk we can do the data transformation.

```
awk -F ' -- ' '
{
  # populate the array
  a[++N] = $1; split($2, t, " ")
  for (k in t) { a[++N] = t[k] }
}
END {ORS = ""
  for (c=i=1; i<=N/NR; i++) {
    for (j=i; j<=N; j+=N/NR) {
      print a[j] (c++%NR ? "\t" : "\n")
    }
  }
}
' file
Frequencies IR Inten
1403.6738   25.0809
1403.6738   25.0809
1403.6738   25.0809
```

Basic idea is to first populate the array and record the length of the array at the end. Then chop the array into N/NR parts and pick corresponding elements from each portion. In other languages like Python this operation is called `zip`.